# FileObserver not working for storage/emulated/0/

Tags: android

I have an issue when working with FileObserver.
I want to catch the event FileObserver.CREATE path is storage/emulated/0/

Here is my code:

```
public class PathFileObserver extends FileObserver {
    static final String TAG = PathFileObserver.class.getSimpleName();
    /**
     * should be end with File.separator
     */
    String rootPath;
    static final int mask = (FileObserver.CREATE);

    public PathFileObserver(String root) {
        super(root, mask);

        if (!root.endsWith(File.separator)) {
            root += File.separator;
        }
        rootPath = root;
    }
    @Override
    public void onEvent(int event, String path) {

        switch (event) {
            case FileObserver.CREATE:
                Log.d(TAG, "CREATE:" + rootPath + path);
                break;
            default:
                // just ignore
                break;
        }
    }

}

public class FileObserverService extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        initial();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void initial() {
        PathFileObserver pathFileObserver = new PathFileObserver(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
        pathFileObserver.startWatching();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I tested it on the nexus 5, with OS version 6.0.

If anyone has a solution for my problem, please let me know.

Comment: you need to add [runtime permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) in Android 6.0+.

Comment: What is the numerical value of CREATE?

Comment: @PrakashU I have requested permission :  Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE at runtime.

Comment: @greenapps i used the CREATE value from FileObserver class.
public static final int CREATE = 0x00000100;

Comment: So that would be 4. I dont see that with 6.0 too. Only 1, 16 and 32.

Comment: With android 4.4.4 no 4 either. But 1;8;16;32;;64;128;256.

Comment: What i can do with this issue ?

Comment: Google? Dont know. Use one of the other values you get?

Comment: i have tried all value from FileObserver class  but still error.